# Searching filename in a textfile

Tags: filenames

I need to search through a text file and find filenames and folders. If a filename is found, display a text and if a folder is found, display another text.

can anyone suggest how to do it?

```
cat filenames.txt | while read line
do
echo $line
done
```

Comment: do u want to search an string in a text? or a string in folder and file recursively?

Comment: Can you provide the textfile or any format of the textfile?